Exporting of data is failing in Sitecore Content Hub
I am trying to create an export package of all the data from Sitecore Content Hub. I have selected all the entities under the Import/Export section and clicked on the Export tab, but the export consistently fails. Are there any settings that need to be configured before exporting?

Did you look at the logs on why the export is failing? There could be a schema field which might be preventing the export?

Do you have any more information in regards of the error message? Otherwise you always can create a Sitecore Support ticket to help you out.
